# Dependent signature specialization

Tags: sml, smlnj, mlton

Can I specialize a type in a signature using types before that type and in the signature? Here is an example:

```
signature A = sig 
  type t
  type s
end
```

Can I specialize `A` by the following?

```
signature B = A where type s = t list
```

Both SML/NJ and Mlton complain that `t` is unbound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that indeed cannot be done directly. The reasons are rather technical, it is not easy to ascribe a well-behaved semantics to such an operation in the general case.

The closest you can get is by introducing another auxiliary type:

```
signature B =
sig
  type t'
  include A with type t = t' with type s = t' list
end
```